# Solving for $\lambda$ in an exponential distribution given an average

Tags: statistics, exponential-function

Studying for a mid-term, and not sure how to go about the following problem.

Given $t = 700$ as an average, I have to solve for lambda.

I'm thinking since t is determined, I don't need any integrals here, which would give

$$\lambda e^{-\lambda(700)} = .5$$

Assuming this is correct, I'm not sure how to solve for $\lambda$ since by taking the $ln$ I would put a $\lambda$ inside the $ln$.

If I have my formula wrong, then how would I go about solving it? I know I have an exponential distribution, and average "fail" time of 700, and I need to solve for $\lambda$. The rest of the information is just "story problem" story, but I can give it if necessary.

EDIT (Full Story problem):

> Remi works at a large data center, and manages the hard drives for the servers. Assume that the probability density for a single hard drive failing after t days of use follows
>   an exponential distribution. Remi observes that the average failure time for the hard drives is 700 days. Use this to determine $\lambda$.

Comment: This equation cannot be solved algebraically. Maybe you have the wrong equation.

Comment: The median is not equal to the mean, at least for an exponential distribution. Nor is a density a probability.

Comment: the solution is a complex number

Comment: If $T$ has an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$, then $E[T] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ and  $\lambda = \frac{1}{E[T]}$

Comment: It might be helpful, if you would post the rest of the story.

Comment: @calculus, added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value, or average of a variable with exponential distribution is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Comment: I need to know what $\lambda$ is.

Comment: If 700 is the average then $700=\frac{1}{\lambda} \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{1}{700}$. Then the formula is wrong.

Comment: But how do I solve for that? Also I added the full story problem to make sure in case I didn't start it out correctly.

Comment: There is a mistake in your book then.

Comment: How is there a mistake? I didn't say your answer wasn't correct (I don't even have a solution), I just want to know the steps of getting there given the information.

Comment: Look at the [proof](http://www.statlect.com/ucdexp1.htm) that the expected value is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. The problem says that the average failure time is $700$. Therefore $\lambda = \frac{1}{700}$. Plugging in that value in the equation the problem gives yields $\approx 5.2 \times 10^{-4}$